# Returned not counting in counter

Tags: java, arrays, return, counter

I have returned a dice roll for a homework assignment and am having trouble with counting the number of times each number rolled. I returned to roll to main and have added it to an array but it is just not counting. I have tried what people have said and made some changes and am closer but still haven't got the counter right.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many times should I roll the dice? ");
    int userIn = input.nextInt();
    int[] rolls = new int[13];
    rolls[simDiceRoll(userIn)]++;
    for(int i = 2; i < rolls.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " was rolled " + simDiceRoll(userIn) + " times");
    }

}
    public static int simDiceRoll (int userNum) {
        int roll1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        int roll2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        int rolls = roll1 + roll2;
        return rolls;
    }
```

output

```
How many times should I roll the dice? 10000
2 was rolled 10 times
3 was rolled 10 times
4 was rolled 7 times
5 was rolled 5 times
6 was rolled 8 times
7 was rolled 12 times
8 was rolled 9 times
9 was rolled 6 times
10 was rolled 10 times
11 was rolled 6 times
12 was rolled 6 times
```

Comment: Your program does not use any arrays. You might consider looking over a tutorial on Java arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: returned *what* array?

Answer (score 0):

You do have the input of the user that gives the amount of dice rolls you want to make. do use that number in a for loop and just make an array of size 14 of integers. In every loop you are just adding 1 to the array[number rolled] and at last you are looping through every single item in this array like the for that is in your code and printing the value.

I hope that this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have any array in your code. The reason why you get result of "7" each time is because the "int rolls" is being defined **before** the loop, and not inside the loop.

Try to replace the 'rolls' with 'simDiceRoll(userIn)':

```
System.out.println(i + " was rolled " + simDiceRoll(userIn) + " times");
```